# Why doesn't Qt's qHash() have an overload for std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, qt, overloading, shared-ptr, qhash

I just found out, to my surprise, that the following code does not compile out of the box in C++14 using Qt 5.4:

```
QSet<std::shared_ptr<SomeType>> var;
```

The problem is that there is no overload of the `qHash()` method for `std::shared_ptr`, or any other smart pointer as far as I can see:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#related-non-members

It seems natural to me to have the following overload (or something similar):

```
template <typename T>
uint qHash(const std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr, uint seed = 0)
{
    return qHash(ptr.get(), seed);
}
```

but it does not exist. This cannot simply be something the Qt developers overlooked. Do I need to include a special header? What is the reason why this does not exist?

Comment: Is there a good reason why you're mixing Qt's set class and std's smart pointer class? Why not `std::unordered_set` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Speak of the devil, and he doth appear:**
https://codereview.qt-project.org/113340

> This cannot simply be something the Qt developers overlooked.

It's not an overlook, it's just that Qt doesn't have endless resources to add `qHash` overloads to any STL type which has an `operator==`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @peppe. Did you add those overloads to Qt? Thanks a lot for that too :)

Comment: It's just that even if Qt has limited resources, its polish, and maturity, and total awesomeness has spoiled me to expect everything (and getting it almost always :D ).

Answer (score 1):

> This cannot simply be something the Qt developers overlooked.

It is, and it's not something that was overlooked - it simply is impossible to write all the code at once. One has to stop somewhere and do a release. Feel free to submit a code revision that will fix this :) Make sure, though, that the revision will build on all platforms, and with all supported compilers - some of them have libraries without `std::shared_ptr`!